# Creating a column in a rdd based on the existing ones

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working with pyspark. I have loaded a `.csv` file and converted it into rows.
After that I select some of the columns and put them into `NumericalElementsRDD`:

```
NumericalElementsRDD = elementsRDD.map(lambda p: Row(g1=int(p[30]), g2=int(p[31]), g3=int(p[32])))
```

The problem is that I need to create another column, let's call it `success_fail`. The logic behind it is: `success_fail values 1 if p[32] >= 10 else 0`

I have tried to do it inserting another lambda in the expression of elementsRDD.map, but it didn't work.

Could you help me with this task?

Answer (score 0):

To build this is easy.

See, you create a RDD of Rows. To convert it to Dataframe is easy.

```
NumericalElementsDF = NumericalElementsRDD.toDF()
```

After this you can use the function `withColumn()`, this function will create or update an existing column, see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn) the documentation.

Well, how to update? Use this command:

```
NumericalElementsDF.withColumn('g4', when(col('g3') >= 10, 1).otherwise(0))
```

You can see that I used function `when()` that works like if for dataframes see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when).

For python, if you convert your RDD for RDD of Rows. Better you use dataframes to have faster responses.

Comment: Thanks. But I have to insert the column before creating a DF.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build this within RDD, you can try this,

```
condition_Check = lambda v: 1 if v >= 10 else 0
NumericalElementsRDD = elementsRDD.map(lambda p: Row(g1=int(p[30]), g2=int(p[31]), g3=int(p[32]),success_fail=condition_Check(int(p[32]))))
```

Using dataframes or datasets instead of Row type provide better performance.

Comment: Hi Suresh: 
Thanks for your answer. I have programmed it:
def condition_check(v):
  return lambda v: 1 if v >= 10 else 0
NumericalElementsRDD = elementsRDD.map(lambda p: Row( g1=float(p[30]), g2=float(p[31]), g3=float(p[32]), success_fail=condition_check(float(p[32]))))

Unfortunately it seems not to work, because after that:

ElementosNumericosRDD.take(5) 
This take expression is not working and I also get an error message if I try to build a dataframe.